# Netezza Database Projects

Tags: netezza

New to Netezza development having come from a MS BI background.

Are there any tools for developing Netezza databases? e.g. Microsoft lets you create database projects in Visual studio, which allow you to create dacpacs to deploy changes through environments - does Netezza have some equivalent tools?

Thanks,

MrHH

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Aginity Workbench** for Netezza databse development.